# count =0 if query returns null mysql

Tags: mysql

I have mysql DB.

I am running the below query.

```
SELECT cluster,
       infra_properties.property_name property,
       count(*)
FROM   raw_alerts,
       infra_properties
WHERE  infra_properties.parent_group = raw_alerts.cluster
       AND cluster = 'abuse-content'
       AND infra_properties.property_name = 'BigBro'
       AND timestamp BETWEEN '2012-12-24 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-24 23:59:59'
GROUP  BY cluster;
```

I am getting output as null but my requirement is getting the count=0. as mentioned bellow.

```
+---------------+----------+----------+
| cluster       | property | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+----------+
| abuse-content | BigBro   |    0     |
+---------------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)
```

Comment: I ran bellow query but still no luck.                                                                                                                                          select cluster, infra_properties.property_name property, COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) as count from raw_alerts, infra_properties  where infra_properties.parent_group=raw_alerts.cluster and cluster='abuse-content' and infra_properties.property_name='BigBro' and timestamp between '2013-1-24 00:00:00' and '2013-1-24 23:59:59' group by cluster;

Comment: did you try `count(cluster)`?

Comment: yes already tried this

Answer (score 0):

If there is no matching records on the 2 tables then no rows will be returned.

What you probably need to do is have an extra table with cluster and property columns, then do something like:-

```
SELECT a.cluster, a.property, count(c.id)
    FROM SomeExtraTable a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN raw_alerts b ON a.cluster = b.cluster AND AND b.cluster = 'abuse-content'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN infra_properties c 
ON a.property = c.property 
AND c.parent_group = b.cluster
AND c.property_name = 'BigBro' 
AND c.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-12-24 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-24 23:59:59'
    GROUP  BY  a.cluster, a.property
```

(I am only guessing as to what table the timestamp column is on)